# The mimetype of file 'jpg' could not been detected

Tags: zend-framework, file-upload, mime-types

i have a form in my page. that upload a pic to host.

it work nice in localhost! but in host it show me this error:

> The mimetype of file '3-1.jpg' could not been detected

i used of same pic in local and server!!

even i tested that mimetype with this code `$form->archivo->getMimeType()` and it showed me :

> image/jpeg

this is my form code :

```
$pic = new Zend_Form_Element_File('pic');

        $pic -> setLabel('select picture')      
            ->addValidator('Count', false, 1)
            ->addValidator('Size', false, '1MB')
            ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,png,gif')
            ->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data')
            ->addValidator('MimeType', false, array('image/jpeg',  'image/png', 'image/gif'))
            ->setDestination(PUBLIC_DIR . 'upload/product')
            ->addDecorators(array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'label','class'=> "descrip")), array('Label', array('tag' => 'label')));
```

Comment: not sure if that helps as you stated the mime type outputs image/jpeg, but JPEG may also have the following types: image/pjpeg and image/jpg -- I'd give it a try.

Comment: possible help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526286/zend-form-the-mimetype-of-file-foto-jpg-could-not-be-detected

Answer (score 0):

[Zend_Form - The mimetype of file 'foto.jpg' could not be detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526286/zend-form-the-mimetype-of-file-foto-jpg-could-not-be-detected)